# How can I shut down a MS Access DB (kick users off)

Tags: ms-access

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

I am the creator/owner of a MC Access DB that is shared among many users on several different sites.  I recently "split" the DB (a really good move)... the "frontend" is a the_db.accdb file that each user has on their laptop, and the backend is a the_db_be.accdb file that is on a file server the users can access through their frontend.

I need to alter a trigger on one of the tables.  I can't do this because users have the DB open.  Is there a way I can shut the DB down (kick users off) so that I can do this work?  I found lots of stuff on google about closing a DB, but this appears to be from the standpoint of an individual user closing their own connection down, not booting all users off of a DB.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You really want to interrupt a user mid-data entry and corrupt data? Basically, you want to hack user. This is why systems are set up so that user must give permission for their system to be 'taken over' by external entity (e.g. TeamViewer). Unless you are network administrator and can 'push' updates. I worked for a huge company and even when they wanted to do updates, they sent email telling everyone to log off at certain time and system would not be available, usually on Sunday.

Comment: Other DBs allow the DBA to push active users off the DB using methods provided by the DB.  They might prevent new users to get on and let the older ones die out over time, then do their exclusive access work.  They might wait for all open transactions to finish before kicking attached users off.  Or thy might force everyone off immediately, relying on journaling and DB recovery systems to keep the DB from being corrupted.  Point is, the DB has a mechanism for getting users off.  I realize that Access isn't as sophisticated, but was wondering if it has any capability like this at all.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905680/force-all-users-to-disconnect-from-2010-access-backend-database

Comment: Yes, I would email the user community and warn them of the upcoming shut-down.  But for those who do not comply (and there will be some of them), I need a way to get them off without corrupting the DB.  If they are in the middle of editing a record, change some fields but didn't finish, I don't care if that record reverts back to what it was before they started.  I don't even have a way of knowing who is attached to the DB.  I believe you need system privileges to run the tools that can see that (and I'm not a sys admin :-()